# What client to use for load testing comet application irrespective of comet server

Tags: node.js, comet, load-testing, sockjs, cometserver

We are in process of developing an app and we started with:

- Spring SockJs Java server with Servlet 3.0 container (Async support)
- SockJs javascript client.

To test the load aspects, I had written a client using Bayeux API -this was for WebSockets and not for Polling.

Since Node makes strong case for async communication -so we want to evaluate its load capacity against Java server. From articles, I get a feel that Node scales -but we want to keep Java unless there is "significant" advantage going the Node.js way. And most important, we want to try it out for our specific use case rather than riding on popular opinion and hence we want to benchmark them on open connection handling over a period of time, My Question:

- Is it possible to write a common client in JAVA -which can connect to both Java based server as well as NODE? Seems possible because at end its HTPP and does not  matter what exposes it -but am not getting the right client. Even Bayeux does not work for NON websocket use case -Although I used same API to test "Websocket" connection for SockJs, CometD and Node server
- What to do for Non Websocket , for example -Long Polling or streaming any client which can be run against a server "irrespective" whether its in CometD, SockJs or NODE?
- SockJs cleint is a Java script client -we can emulate connections from browser -Is there a Java client for server?

Am new to javascript -so how a load test is written in javascript and how is it run (Socket one cannot be run from browser) -any sample code on github?

Comment: For testing including load-tests, I am a fan of JMeter. You can find it in many linux repositories, ie: apt-get install jmeter The source code and manuals can be found here: http://jmeter.apache.org Does this help you?

Comment: Jmeter is for just HTTP load tests .. It will not emulate comet mechanism as streaming/long polling etc.